What is the meaning of the bitcore tag?
Is the bitcore tag supposed to be for questions about the Bitcore project?  It seems that some people use it (perhaps mistakenly) to talk about the unrelated Bitcoin Core software.
The bitcore tag currently has no description or wiki.  When we figure out what it means, it should get one (possibly including a "not to be confused with..." note).

bitcore means the software developed by BitPay.
Bitcoin Core questions should be tagged with bitcoin-core.

It seems that Nick also edited the tag summary to include that information.
